# DatabaseException when setting mappings of ManagedProperty

Tags: managed-property

When I'm trying to set mappings of an existing mapping:

```
ManagedProperty managedProperty = managedProperties[ManagedPropertyName];
MappingCollection mappings = managedProperty.GetMappings();
List<CrawledProperty> allCrawledProperties = new List<CrawledProperty>();
foreach (Category category in searchSchema.AllCategories)
{
  allCrawledProperties.AddRange(category.GetAllCrawledProperties());
}

foreach (string name in this.CrawledPropertyNames)
{
  CrawledProperty crawledProperty = allCrawledProperties.Where(cp => cp.Name.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault();
  Mapping newMapping = new Mapping();
  newMapping.CrawledPropset = crawledProperty.Propset;
  newMapping.CrawledPropertyName = crawledProperty.Name;
  newMapping.ManagedPid = managedProperty.PID;
  if (!mappings.Contains(newMapping))
  {
    mappings.Add(newMapping);
  }
}

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
  managedProperty.SetMappings(mappings);
});
```

I'm getting following DatabaseException:

> `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.DatabaseException: There was an internal problem connecting to or querying the database.
>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SchemaDatabase.WrapFunction[T](String functionName, Func 1 wrappedFunction)
>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedProperty.SetMappingsInternal(MappingCollection mappings)`

The managed property was created programmatically by me before.

Am I missing something?

Best regards, Hagen

Answer (score 0):

hagenstrahl!

It happens when SharePoint Search config is wrong. 
This article can help you [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

My problem was: SP Search application pool run under farm account, but my code run under service account. When i tryed read all crawled properties, then catched DatabaseException.

I resolve problem with article above. I use accounts: spservice (for search pools, same as webApp pools), spcontent (for search crawler). After create Search service not forget add account ("spadmin", example) to administrators of service.